# xdotool how to do horizontal scrolling?

Tags: bash, shell, horizontal-scrolling, mousewheel, xdotool

I'm writing a bash script to control a browser remotely. So far I have vertical scrolling implemented using

```
xdotool click 4 //up
xdotool click 5 //down
```

**How can I implement horizontal scrolling using xdotool?** I saw numbers 6 and 7 mentioned on some site, but that did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a click, you can send the Left or Right arrow keys:

`xdotool key Right`
`xdotool key Left`

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't do everytime. For example, on spreadsheets, the selector will just move left/right to the adjacent cell rather than scrolling the whole work space sideways.

Answer (score 2):

Just use these:

```
xdotool click 6 # left
xdotool click 7 # right
```